# Simple reusable JavaScript toggle() script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-reuse

I am in the process of learning JavaScript and am not sure how to tackle a simple snippet of reusable code.

What I need is a piece of code that will hide() #body01, #body02, #body03, 04,05 etc (all of them). Then when I click title01 it understands I want to toggle() body01. If I click title02, it will toggle() body02 and so forth.

```
<a id="title01">Title 1</a>
<div id="body01">Body content for Title 1</div>

<a id="title02">Title 2</a>
<div id="body02">Body content for Title 2</div>

<a id="title03">Title 3</a>
<div id="body03">Body content for Title 3</div>
```

Sorry if this has been asked, I have not been able to find it nor figure it out myself.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have to use straight javascript or can you use jQuery or some other library? jQuery has a toggle() method. Also what have you tried? Post the javascript you've tried so far.

Comment: as a newbie i recommend you start using jQuery it will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jQuery (if not, you should), it's as simple as this:

```
$('[id^=title]').click(function(){

    var tmp = $(this).attr('id').split("title");
    $('#body'+tmp[1]).toggle();

});
```

Comment: If the body divs are always right after the title divs, I would recommend Sarfraz's solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this with jQuery using [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method:

```
$(function(){
  $("[id^=title]").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
    return false; // prevent moving down or going to link
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Too often new JS developers go right into jQuery without learning JavaScript as a language first. You most definitely should learn at least some plain JavaScript so that you will be able to better understand and use jQuery's powerful features. The best way to toggle is by setting and removing a class as opposed to setting a style property on an element. That being said you could do something like this.

.hidden { display: none; }

```
    <div>
        <a id="title01" class="toggler">Title 1</a>
        <div class="body" id="body01">Body content for Title 1</div>

        <a id="title02" class="toggler">Title 2</a>
        <div class="body" id="body02">Body content for Title 2</div>

        <a id="title03" class="toggler">Title 3</a>
        <div class="body" id="body03">Body content for Title 3</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // set your initial variables
        // ideally you will put these in a function which is not
        // exposed to the global object
        var togglers = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
            divs   = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
            i, j;

        // here you loop through your a elements and if they have
        // a class of toggler you assign the onclick event to a toggle function
        for ( i = 0; i < togglers.length; i += 1) {
            if (togglers[i].className == 'toggler') {
                togglers[i].onclick = toggle;
            }
        }

        function toggle() {
            // here you will cache the variable toToggle
            // which is the div you want to toggle
            var toToggle;

            // loop through all divs and if they have a class of body
            // you hide it
            for (j = 0; j < divs.length; j += 1) {
                if (divs[j].className == 'body') {
                    divs[j].className += ' hidden';

                    // this is tricky for a beginner. nodeType 1 is an element node
                    // nextSibling will get the nextSibling but if there is white space
                    // in your document it will return a text node when you have to toggle
                    // an element node. this just ensures that it will keep going until it
                    // finds and element node
                    if (this.nextSibling.nodeType !== 1) {
                        toToggle = this.nextSibling.nextSibling;
                    }
                    // then you toggle it by removing the hidden class
                    toToggle.className = 'body';
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

and here are a couple of links to refer to nodeType and next sibling.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nextSibling

Comment: I disagree, I've skipped Javascript as a whole when learning jQuery and every time I look at some standard Javascript I feel like I made the right choice.

Comment: it's all a matter of opinion i suppose. if you have no interest in being a professional javascript developer then it may not matter since jQuery provides so many plugins. that being said, i still think it's beneficial to know what makes jQuery do what it does.

Comment: Well, I think saying 'if you have no interest in being a professional javascript developer' is taking it a bit far. I'm writing most 'jQuery plugins' myself so I'm still programming, I'm just using the easier and more logical (to me) method.

Comment: Ok maybe that was extreme. It just comes down to your own opinion. I wanted to know how jQuery did what it did so I started to learn JavaScript. There are many cases where I can now write a quick function in plain JavaScript where as before I would load the entire jQuery library and not use 3/4 of it. So it is a huge benefit for me knowing JavaScript as opposed to just knowing jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Add classes to your DOM elements, like this:

```
<a class="title" id="title01" href="">Title 1</a>
<div class="body" id="body01">Body content for Title 1</div>

<a class="title" id="title02" href="">Title 2</a>
<div class="body" id="body02">Body content for Title 2</div>

<a class="title" id="title03" href="">Title 3</a>
<div class="body" id="body03">Body content for Title 3</div>
```

Then you can add the toggle functionality like this:

```
$('.title').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.body').toggle();
});
```

Here is a demo for the [accordion like jQuery functionality](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/TzUCd/)